# What is the proper syntax for getting a Makefile to print the output directory of one of its output zip files?

Tags: android, makefile

I'm trying to edit an Android Makefile in the hopes of getting it to print out the directory (path) location of one the ZIP files it creates.  Ideally, since the build process is long and does many things, I would like for it print out the pathway to the ZIP file to a text file in a different directory I can access later:

Pseudo-code idea:

```
# print the desired pathway to output file
print(getDirectoryOf(variable-name.zip)) > ~/Desktop/location_of_file.txt
```

The Makefile snippet where I would like to insert this new bit of code is shown below.  I am interested in finding the directory of **$(name).zip** (that is specific file I want to locate):

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------
# A zip of the directories that map to the target filesystem.
# This zip can be used to create an OTA package or filesystem image
# as a post-build step.
#
name := $(TARGET_PRODUCT)
ifeq ($(TARGET_BUILD_TYPE),debug)
  name := $(name)_debug
endif
name := $(name)-target_files-$(FILE_NAME_TAG)

intermediates := $(call intermediates-dir-for,PACKAGING,target_files)
BUILT_TARGET_FILES_PACKAGE := $(intermediates)/$(name).zip
$(BUILT_TARGET_FILES_PACKAGE): intermediates := $(intermediates)
$(BUILT_TARGET_FILES_PACKAGE): \
        zip_root := $(intermediates)/$(name)

# $(1): Directory to copy
# $(2): Location to copy it to
# The "ls -A" is to prevent "acp s/* d" from failing if s is empty.
define package_files-copy-root
  if [ -d "$(strip $(1))" -a "$$(ls -A $(1))" ]; then \
    mkdir -p $(2) && \
    $(ACP) -rd $(strip $(1))/* $(2); \
  fi
endef
```

Comment: This isn't really a good place for the new code. You should find the rule that builds `$(name).zip`, not just the rules that set variables for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As part of your rule's action (that is, as one of the lines indented by a tab, or as a command that follows a semicolon):

```
@echo $(dir $(variable-name).zip)
```

If output to a file is desired,

```
@echo $(dir $(variable-name).zip) >~/Desktop/location_of_file.txt
```

and you can make the `>` a `>>` if you prefer to append to the file rather than to overwrite.

**UPDATE**

What does it mean, "As part of your rule's action (that is, as one of the lines indented by a tab, or as a command that follows a semicolon)"?

*Answer:*  It means that you can @echo like this:

```
file-to-be-built: dependencies
        some-command
        @echo foo
        another-command
```

Or like this:

```
file-to-be-built: dependencies
        @some-command; \
        echo foo; \
        another-command
```

(note the placement of the `@`).  Or like this:

```
file-to-be-built: dependencies; @some-command; echo foo; another-command
```

But not like this:

```
@echo foo
file-to-be-built: dependencies
        some-command
        another-command
```

(Here is yet another parenthetical statement, which you can ignore if you like:  The `@`, as you may know, suppresses Make's copying of the command itself to standard output.  You can omit it, of course, but if you include it then you must put it before the specific command you don't want Make to copy.  Formally, the versions without semicolons issue multiple, separate commands in their own, separate environments, using separate invocations of the shell; whereas the versions with semicolons only invoke the shell once, with a single environment, and leave it to the shell to separate and execute the commands.  Does this make sense?  Maybe not, if you just read it -- I can't make much sense of such tangled verbiage, either, even though I wrote it, myself -- but do try it with the `@` in the various spots indicated and it should soon start to make sense to you.  The `@` is no big deal in any case, but it's there to use to keep Make's output clean if you understand how to use it.)

Comment: Thank you.  However, this "echo" command I assume prints this information to the terminal/console, correct?  How would you route this echo statement to an output text file for example?

Comment: Fair enough.  I have revised my answer accordingly.  Good luck.

Comment: Incidentally, the `echo` command is usually a shell builtin.  Make itself does not know what to do with it, but only does the indicated `$(dir)` substitution and then passes the resulting command to the shell for handling.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This is helpful and what I wanted to find.

Also, is there any chance you could provide me a code example of what you mean by that parenthetical statement?  (in other words, usage in a rule or after semicolon, perhaps even in the code snippet I posted above?)

Comment: Ironically, the answer to your follow-up question is substantially longer than the answer to the original; but it is now posted above and you can make of it what you will.

Comment: Thank you yet again.  The parenthetical is useful, and your examples are clear.  I think this is a pretty thorough answer now for anyone interested in editing a make file to do something like I want.

I just wanted to understand all the specifics b/c I am editing a developer's Makefile, and I do not want to break it with incorrect syntax with just a minor edit to get some directory locations.